# Using IFilter from a 32bit app on a x64 system

Tags: c++, full-text-search, ifilter

I need to use an IFilter interface from a 32bit app on **Windows x64** systems. This is easy for .doc files as offfilt.dll supports both build types. However, I need to also get the plain text from .docx and other files types. The solution at first is to install [Microsoft Filter Packs](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17062). However, only the x64 version will install ... which means my 32bit app can't use them. They work great under 32bit Windows.

Has anyone found a way around this?

Answer (score 7):

I found a way to install docx Filter Pack 32bits in a 64bits OS. To other file formats is similar.

1. Install Filter Pack 32 bits in a 32bits OS;
2. Copy ifilters files in
   directory “C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Filters”
   from 32 bits OS to the a directory “C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
   Files\Microsoft Shared\Filters” in 64bits OS.
3. Copy the following lines to a file “ifilter.reg” and execute the file:

File's content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.docx\PersistentHandler]
@="{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.docm\PersistentHandler]
@="{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dotx\PersistentHandler]
@="{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.docm\PersistentHandler]
@="{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.docx\PersistentHandler]
@="{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.dotx\PersistentHandler]
@="{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}]
@="Office Open XML Format Word Persistent Handler"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}\PersistentAddinsRegistered]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}\PersistentAddinsRegistered\{89BCB740-6119-101A-BCB7-00DD010655AF}]
@="{5A98B233-3C59-4B31-944C-0E560D85E6C3}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}]
@="Office Open XML Format Word Persistent Handler"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}\PersistentAddinsRegistered]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}\PersistentAddinsRegistered\{89BCB740-6119-101A-BCB7-00DD010655AF}]
@="{5A98B233-3C59-4B31-944C-0E560D85E6C3}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{5A98B233-3C59-4B31-944C-0E560D85E6C3}\InprocServer32]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\Filters\\offfiltx.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{5A98B233-3C59-4B31-944C-0E560D85E6C3}\InprocServer32]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\Filters\\offfiltx.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}\PersistentAddinsRegistered\{89BCB740-6119-101A-BCB7-00DD010655AF}]
@="{5A98B233-3C59-4B31-944C-0E560D85E6C3}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Extending Rui answer with windows registry script for 3 file formats (Word, Excel, PowerPoint). Hope, will safe time for somebody as it worked well:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.docx\PersistentHandler]
@="{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pptx\PersistentHandler]
@="{4F46F75F-199F-4C63-8B7D-86D48FE7970C}"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlsx\PersistentHandler]
@="{4887767F-7ADC-4983-B576-88FB643D6F79}"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.docm\PersistentHandler]
@="{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pptm\PersistentHandler]
@="{4F46F75F-199F-4C63-8B7D-86D48FE7970C}"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlsm\PersistentHandler]
@="{4887767F-7ADC-4983-B576-88FB643D6F79}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dotx\PersistentHandler]
@="{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.docm\PersistentHandler]
@="{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.docx\PersistentHandler]
@="{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.pptm\PersistentHandler]
@="{4F46F75F-199F-4C63-8B7D-86D48FE7970C}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.pptx\PersistentHandler]
@="{4F46F75F-199F-4C63-8B7D-86D48FE7970C}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.xlsm\PersistentHandler]
@="{4887767F-7ADC-4983-B576-88FB643D6F79}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.xlsx\PersistentHandler]
@="{4887767F-7ADC-4983-B576-88FB643D6F79}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.dotx\PersistentHandler]
@="{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}]
@="Office Open XML Format Word Persistent Handler"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{4F46F75F-199F-4C63-8B7D-86D48FE7970C}]
@="Office Open XML Format PowerPoint Persistent Handler"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{4887767F-7ADC-4983-B576-88FB643D6F79}]
@="Office Open XML Format Excel Persistent Handler"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}\PersistentAddinsRegistered]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{4F46F75F-199F-4C63-8B7D-86D48FE7970C}\PersistentAddinsRegistered]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{4887767F-7ADC-4983-B576-88FB643D6F79}\PersistentAddinsRegistered]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}\PersistentAddinsRegistered\{89BCB740-6119-101A-BCB7-00DD010655AF}]
@="{5A98B233-3C59-4B31-944C-0E560D85E6C3}"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{4F46F75F-199F-4C63-8B7D-86D48FE7970C}\PersistentAddinsRegistered\{89BCB740-6119-101A-BCB7-00DD010655AF}]
@="{DDFE337F-4987-4EC8-BDE3-133FA63D5D85}"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{4887767F-7ADC-4983-B576-88FB643D6F79}\PersistentAddinsRegistered\{89BCB740-6119-101A-BCB7-00DD010655AF}]
@="{F90DFE0C-CBDF-41FF-8598-EDD8F222A2C8}"


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}]
@="Office Open XML Format Word Persistent Handler"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{4F46F75F-199F-4C63-8B7D-86D48FE7970C}]
@="Office Open XML Format PowerPoint Persistent Handler"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{4887767F-7ADC-4983-B576-88FB643D6F79}]
@="Office Open XML Format Excel Persistent Handler"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}\PersistentAddinsRegistered]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{4F46F75F-199F-4C63-8B7D-86D48FE7970C}\PersistentAddinsRegistered]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{4887767F-7ADC-4983-B576-88FB643D6F79}\PersistentAddinsRegistered]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}\PersistentAddinsRegistered\{89BCB740-6119-101A-BCB7-00DD010655AF}]
@="{5A98B233-3C59-4B31-944C-0E560D85E6C3}"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{4F46F75F-199F-4C63-8B7D-86D48FE7970C}\PersistentAddinsRegistered\{89BCB740-6119-101A-BCB7-00DD010655AF}]
@="{DDFE337F-4987-4EC8-BDE3-133FA63D5D85}"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{4887767F-7ADC-4983-B576-88FB643D6F79}\PersistentAddinsRegistered\{89BCB740-6119-101A-BCB7-00DD010655AF}]
@="{F90DFE0C-CBDF-41FF-8598-EDD8F222A2C8}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{5A98B233-3C59-4B31-944C-0E560D85E6C3}\InprocServer32]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\Filters\\offfiltx.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{DDFE337F-4987-4EC8-BDE3-133FA63D5D85}\InprocServer32]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\Filters\\offfiltx.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{4887767F-7ADC-4983-B576-88FB643D6F79}\InprocServer32]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\Filters\\offfiltx.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{5A98B233-3C59-4B31-944C-0E560D85E6C3}\InprocServer32]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\Filters\\offfiltx.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{DDFE337F-4987-4EC8-BDE3-133FA63D5D85}\InprocServer32]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\Filters\\offfiltx.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{F90DFE0C-CBDF-41FF-8598-EDD8F222A2C8}\InprocServer32]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\Filters\\offfiltx.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{D3B41FA1-01E3-49AF-AA25-1D0D824275AE}\PersistentAddinsRegistered\{89BCB740-6119-101A-BCB7-00DD010655AF}]
@="{5A98B233-3C59-4B31-944C-0E560D85E6C3}"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{4F46F75F-199F-4C63-8B7D-86D48FE7970C}\PersistentAddinsRegistered\{89BCB740-6119-101A-BCB7-00DD010655AF}]
@="{DDFE337F-4987-4EC8-BDE3-133FA63D5D85}"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{4F46F75F-199F-4C63-8B7D-86D48FE7970C}\PersistentAddinsRegistered\{89BCB740-6119-101A-BCB7-00DD010655AF}]
@="{F90DFE0C-CBDF-41FF-8598-EDD8F222A2C8}"
```

Answer (score 1):

As you found out, there isn't a supported way to install the 32-bit filters on a 64-bit system, see reply from MSFT near the end of this post: [How can I install the 32 bit Office Filter Pack on a 64 bit system?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlookdev/thread/34a0da77-7535-4262-bb94-c14585c4d17b).

The solution suggested there, is to create a helper program to do the filtering and pass the data back to the main application.

There are a number of ways to do IPC in Windows, so pick the one that works for you. I've created a service that uses WCF to easily create a remote proxy that makes the operation very transparent to the main application.